# How to sort a dc.js pie chart by its values instead of by its keys

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

The default sorting is embedded in dc.js:

```
function pieLayout () {
        return d3.pie().sort(null).value(_chart.cappedValueAccessor);
    }
```

I would like to override this default and sort by Value instead of Key.

Is there a function I am missing that will do this or is there a way to select the chart using d3 and sort using something like this:

```
d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) { return d.freq; });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dc.js, sorting is handled through [BaseMixin.ordering()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#ordering__anchor).

The line you have quoted disables D3's sorting because dc.js has already sorted the data. (Looks like `pie.sort` [already defaults to null](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#pie_sort), so this may be redundant.)

The default for all CapMixin charts (pie and row) is to sort from largest value to smallest. (Clockwise from the top for the pie.)

```
this.ordering(kv => -kv.value);
```

[source](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/df993a6f7ff56c4f903e80544ac7725dec28363d/src/base/cap-mixin.js#L37)

If you're seeing alphabetic ordering, a likely reason is that your group reduce values are objects, which will coerce to NaN in the above expression. Sorting fails and the `group.all()` sorting is preserved, [which is by key](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_all). If this is the case, you may want something like

```
pieChart.ordering(kv => -kv.value.freq)
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was an idiot and using: ".ordering(function (d) { return (d.value.Headcount).toFixed(2) });"  and tofixed() returns a formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with dc.js, but the returned object from `dc.pieLayout` is actually a pie chart generator. That means that you can always override the properties of the returned object, by calling `.sort()` on the return value:

```
var pieLayout = dc.pieLayout()
    .sort(function(d) { return d.value });
```

This will override the default set by dc.js